# Jquery code is working only on the first element when used in foreach loop

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm trying to create a program with laravel and JQuery where if I click on the image name, the image gets displayed. But, the problem is the names of the images are being retrieved from a database using a foreach loop. By doing this only the first element is working. How do I fix my code so that on click I'm able to access the other elements as well?

```
<script>
    $("#theimage").hide();
    $("#nameofimages").on('click',function(){
       $("#theimage").toggle();
    });
</script>

@section('content')
    @foreach($images as $image)
        <p id="nameofimages">{{ $image->imagenames }}</p>
        <img id="theimage" src="/images/{{ $image->imagelocation }}">
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: Can you please post your code also..?

Comment: Can you show us code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only first one is working because you have used id instead of class. id can refer to only one element in the DOM.

```
<script>
    $("#theimage").hide();
    $(".nameofimages").on('click',function(){
       $(".theimage").toggle();
    });
</script>

@section('content')
    @foreach($images as $image)
        <p class="nameofimages">{{ $image->imagenames }}</p>
        <img class="theimage" src="/images/{{ $image->imagelocation }}">
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: this script will toggle all images in the document.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not working because you are using id for hiding. in dom id should be unique

second things if you are going to use hide() method when document is ready. then you should use css in the place of JS. like

```
 <style>
 .theimage{
   display:none
  }
</style>
```

i am updating your laravel template code little bit. add a div for wrapper

```
@section('content')
   @foreach($images as $image)
   <div>
    <p class="nameofimages">{{ $image->imagenames }}</p>
    <img class="theimage" src="/images/{{ $image->imagelocation }}">
  </div>
@endforeach
@endsection
```

now we can show only particular image when we click on there name.

```
<script>
$(".nameofimages").on('click',function(){
    $(this).siblings(".theimage").toggle();
});
</script>
```